# Supremum of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I have this sequence

$$  
\begin{cases}
x_1=3 \newline  x_{n+1}=(-1)^{n}\sqrt{3+2|x_n|}\\ 
\end{cases}$$

I have to find the $\inf {x_{2n}}$ and $\sup{x_{2n}}$
but when I try to check the second condition of $\inf$ and $\sup$ it doesn't make sense.

Comment: What about it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Have you tried computing a few values $x_i?$ You might notice something.

Comment: I see that this is a constant function always tends to -3

Comment: It's not constant but $x_n=\begin{cases}3&n\ odd\\ -3&n\ even\end{cases}$.

Comment: "ut when I try to check the second condition of inf and sup it doesn't make sense." The first condition if if $s =\inf x_{2n}$ then $s$ is a lower bound of $x_{2n}$.  As $x_{2k} =-3$ for all $x_{2k}$ we have $-3 \le x_{2k}=-3$ for all $x_{2k}$.  So $-3$ is a lower bound of $x_{2n}$.  That's done.  The second condition is that if $a > s$ then $a$ is not a lower bound.  If $a>-3$ then $a_2 =-3 < a$ so $a_2 < a$.  Furthermore *all* $x_{2k}=-3< a$.  So $a$ can not be a lower bound for any $a>-3$. That's the second condition.  So $-3$ satifsies the two conditions.  So $-3=\inf x_{2n}$....

Comment: Same can show $\sup x_{2n} = -3$.  For all $x_{2k}$ we have $x_{2x}=-3 \le -3$ and if $b < -3$ then $b < -3 = x_{2k}$ for all $x_{2k}$.  So $\sup x_{2n} = -3$. .... In general, if $x_{k_i}$ is a constant subsequence so that $x_{k_i} = c$ a constant.  Then $\inf x_{k_i} = \sup x_{k_i} = c$.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are looking for the supremum/infimum of the whole sequence or just a subsequence but writing a few terms here gives you
$$x_1 = 3 \\
x_2 = (-1)^1 \sqrt{3+2|x_1|} = -\sqrt{3+2\cdot 3} = -\sqrt{9} = -3 \\
x_3 = (-1)^2 \sqrt{3+2|x_2|} = \sqrt{3+2\cdot 3} = \sqrt{9} = 3 \\
\vdots$$
You can convince yourself that $x_{2k-1} = 3$ and $x_{2k} = -3$ for $k \geq 1$.